# Magento 2 - Set global variable

Tags: magento2, url, global-variable

I want to know if it's possible to add a global variable all through the site (so that if I need to change it, I would only need to do it once).

It's for an URL.

Comment: Can you please give more context on what you're trying to do and why?

Comment: Let me know if you have any issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You can use core session to store the value to access globally**

```
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface as CoreSession;

class MyClass
{

    protected $_coreSession;

    public function __construct(
        ...
        CoreSession $coreSession
        ...
    ) {
        $this->_coreSession = $coreSession;
    }

    public function setValue(){
        $this->_coreSession->start();
        $this->_coreSession->setMyVariable('My variable value');
    }
}
```

**Now you can get your variable value anywhere by core seesion**

```
    public function getValue(){
        $this->_coreSession->start();
        return $this->_coreSession->getMyVariable();
    }
```

**You can also unset session variable by**

```
    public function unsetValue(){
        $this->_coreSession->start();
        return $this->_coreSession->unsMyVariable();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, can you answer please? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/290074/magento-2-get-cookie-just-next-after-set-it