# How can I set a global variable in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, session, global-variable

The scenario is I want to set my variable to a global variable from a phtml file and call in a module file or block file.

So what would be some code or tutorial link that I set my variable to global and call in a module or class file?

Comment: check this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/232079)

Comment: What is a phtml file?

Comment: use this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232078/magento-2-set-global-variable

Comment: Use this link, that will solve your issue. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232078/magento-2-set-global-variable

Answer (score 2):

You can use the code as below for setting up the session below code explains how to set a session in the customer session.

```
protected $customerSession;
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession, 
    ...
){
    ...
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    ...
}

// later in your class you can use it as below

$this->customerSession->myName('anyname');
```

Few other sessions in Magento 2:

- \Magento\Backend\Model\Session
- \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session
- \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
- \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
- \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Session

Links to tutorials:

https://www.mageplaza.com/how-set-unset-session-magento-2.html
http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-set-unset-get-session/

Answer (score 1):

Create your custom variable using `System -> Custom Variables` .Using this you can add your global variable and use is anywhere in magento.

Comment: I want to set a variable in session and call on other page

Comment: Hi Jhon please review this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94265/how-to-set-retrieve-and-unset-session-variables-in-magento-2

Answer (score 0):

To set and get global variable in Magento 2 to follow below steps

1) create the variable in admin side go to **System -> Other Settings -> Custom Variables**

2) add Variable Code, Variable Name, Variable HTML Value(if you want any html value into phtml file) and Variable Plain Value(if you want any plain value into phtml file)

3) get created variable value into phtml file or anywhere in your code

```
protected $objectManager;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
){
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
}

public function execute()
{
   $model = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Variable\Model\Variable')->loadByCode('test_var');//your Variable Code
   $plain_value = $model->getPlainValue();
   $html_value = $model->getHtmlValue();
   $name = $model->getName();
}
```

you can also set like a session [variable](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/232079/55928) and this [one](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94265/how-to-set-retrieve-and-unset-session-variables-in-magento-2/209343#209343)

Comment: how can i pass my own variable in it for example i save calue in variable and i want to pass that value on variable

Comment: in your case, you should use session variable try this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232078/magento-2-set-global-variable/232079#232079) as already mentioned in above answer

Comment: yeah i use this links pls can you helo me that how can i echo that value in get message ?

Comment: check here this is nice answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/209343 just replace setMessage or getMessage with your variable like setCalue and getCalue