# Magento 2 : Get cookie just next after set it

Tags: magento2, php, cookie

**let's say we have executes below magento-2 code at one single request,**

```
namespace namespace\CookieDemo\Model;

/**
 * Class Cookie
 */
class Cookie
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface CookieManagerInterface
     */
    private $cookieManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory CookieMetadataFactory
     */
    private $cookieMetadataFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory
    ) {
        $this->cookieManager = $cookieManager;
        $this->cookieMetadataFactory = $cookieMetadataFactory;
    }

    /** Set Custom Cookie using Magento 2 */
    public function setCustomCookie()
    {
        $publicCookieMetadata = $this->cookieMetadataFactory->createPublicCookieMetadata();
        $publicCookieMetadata->setDurationOneYear();
        $publicCookieMetadata->setPath('/');
        $publicCookieMetadata->setHttpOnly(false);

        return $this->cookieManager->setPublicCookie(
            'magento2cookie',
            'Custom_Cookie_Value',
            $publicCookieMetadata
        );
    }

    /** Get Custom Cookie using */
    public function getCustomCookie()
    {
        return $this->cookieManager->getCookie(
            'magento2cookie'
        );
    }
}
```

Let's say we are calling it anyhow for temp.

```
$object->setCustomCookie(); // cookie has been set
echo $object->getCustomCookie(); // This will print nothing at first request. what if I want to get value of cookie here?
```

But whenever we will make another request we will get the value because cookie has been set already.

Please provide solution to save my day. Thanks in advance.